# "Don't know what the name is" vs. "Don't know what it's called"

Tags: differences, expressions, conversation

What is the difference between saying:

> A: Which meal do you want, Sir?
>   B: Number 4. I don't know what the name is.
>
> A: Which meal do you want, Sir?
>   B: Number 4. I don't know what it's called.

Comment: The difference was explained in Lewis Carroll's *[Through the Looking-Glass](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/12/12-h/12-h.htm)*. Search for the text, **HADDOCKS' EYES**, which you'll find towards the end of Chapter 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For most listeners, the two examples will communicate the same thing, that speaker B doesn't know the name of meal #4.  Technically, of course, B might know the name but not know what the name *is* or what the meal is called, etc.  Here is a [classic example](http://homepages.tcp.co.uk/~nicholson/alice.html),  that illustrates several distinctions:

> "Or else what?" said Alice, for the Knight had made a sudden pause.
>
> "Or else it doesn't, you know. The name of the song is called '*Haddocks' Eyes*.'"
>
> "Oh, that's the name of the song, is it?" Alice said, trying to feel interested.
>
> "No, you don't understand," the Knight said, looking a little vexed. "That's what the name is *called*. The name really is '*The Aged, Aged Man*.'"
>
> "Then I ought to have said 'That's what the *song* is called'?" Alice corrected herself.
>
> "No you oughtn't: that's another thing. The *song* is called '*Ways and Means*' but that's only what it's *called*, you know!"
>
> "Well, what *is* the song then?" said Alice, who was by this time completely bewildered.
>
> "I was coming to that," the Knight said. "The song really *is* '*A-sitting On a Gate*': and the
>   tune's my own invention." ...

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, to most listeners, "the name of the meal" and "what the meal is called" would be the same thing. There may sometimes be a difference if the meal has a *formal* name, but is often informally called something else.

This is more typical for a person, who might have the legal name John Smith, but is almost always called Jack (which is a standard variation on the name John). Only one is his name, but the other is "what he is called".