# "Named" vs "called"

Tags: expressions, word-usage, programming

Over on Stackoverflow, I keep seeing questions wherein posters say:

*I have an item *named* `SoAndSo` (a table, a file, etc.).

Shouldn't it be:

*I have an item *called* `SoAndSo`.

Is "named" an acceptable word in this context? 
Are those words specific to a particular English speakers, e.g. UK vs. USA vs. Australia, etc.?

Comment: You really should ask but one question at a time, not two as you have done here. The second one is answered [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/129360).

Comment: "My father's family _name_ being Pirrip, and my Christian _name_ Philip, my infant tongue could make of both _names_ nothing longer or more explicit than Pip. So, I _called_ myself Pip, and came to be _called_ Pip." Charles Dickens

Comment: @anongoodnurse "The name of the song is called “Haddocks’ Eyes.”’ ‘Oh, that’s the name of the song, is it?’ Alice said, trying to feel interested.‘No, you don’t understand,’ the Knight said, looking a little vexed. ‘That’s what the name is called. The name really is “The Aged Aged Man.”’‘Then I ought to have said “That’s what the song is called”?’ Alice corrected herself.‘No, you oughtn’t: that’s quite another thing! The song is called “Ways and Means”: but that’s only what it’s called, you know!’‘Well, what is the song, then?’ said Alice, who was by this time completely bewildered." Carroll

Comment: I am named Raphael Andreas Blass. I am called Andreas by some people, Andy by some people, Opa by some people, etc.

Comment: Programmers must decide what names to assign to items. They might name them SoAndSoAAA and SoAndSoBBB. Good names are ones that others can read and understand their purpose when they come along later to fix problems (and the creators are gone).

Comment: Lewis Carroll creates amusement from the differences between "named" and "called" in _Through the Looking Glass_, Chapter Eight - "It's my own invention". See [Haddock's Eyes](http://haddockseyes.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the name of the item is indeed *SoAndSo*, then it is reasonable and correct to refer to it as an “item named *SoAndSo*”.  If in addition to being named *SoAndSo* it usually is called *SoAndSo*, it still is ok to  refer to it as an item named *SoAndSo* (and also would be ok to  refer to it as an item called *SoAndSo*).

But if, although usually called *SoAndSo*, it actually has some name other than that, then it would be incorrect to refer to it as an “item named *SoAndSo*”.

Some further examples appear in answers to    [“Don’t know what the name is” vs. “Don’t know what it’s called”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/63565).

Comment: This sounds very strange, as though they were proper nouns. One doesn’t have a table named “So and so”, nor a door, nor a stone or stump.  Maybe a cat or a rat or a unicorn, or even a peasant, but we don’t normally name common nouns.

Comment: @tchrist, throughout history many tables, doors, stones, and stumps have been specifically named.

Comment: @tchrist: It's especially common to have *names* for things in computing. Especially since *calling* something is very different than *naming* something. (I'm thinking particularly of functions, but in many other cases as well, it's actually more natural to say that an item is *named* whatever.)

Comment: @tchrist I presume in this case, table is 'database table', which would indeed have a name.

Answer (score 11):

You should definitely use ***named*** to describe a table, function or any other software construct, especially if it is in a written context. It isn't a matter of formality, but more like notation in math, where you say a "variable named X".

If describing an alias, one might be more likely to use ***called***.

Here's an **[explanation that is specific to programming](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/variables.html)**, emphasis mine:

> A **variable is a symbolic name** for (or reference to) information. The
>   variable's name represents what information the variable contains.
>   They are called variables because the represented information can
>   change but the operations on the variable remain the same... This is
>   similar to mathematics...

Answer (score 3):

Using the word *named* in that context, sounds very formal. Here in the UK, people usually use the word *called*.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught in Catholic English that a person is 'named' Smith not that a person is 'called' Smith.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).